# Challenges in Upgrading ClickHouse from 1.1.54343 to 19.*

Tags: database, nosql, clickhouse

i am new to clickhouse So, i want to update my clickhouse version 1.1.54231 to 19.6.2.11 in Production Environment I have few doubts.

- Do i need to take a backup  of my data before Upgrade of version or upgrade process takes care of data fail overs and  corruptions . 
  To upgrade i am using this command please suggest if any better way possible

sudo apt-get update install --only-upgrade clickhouse-*

- I am using Ubuntu 16.04 in Production any precautions i should need to take while upgrading.
- which is the most stable 19.* version i should need to go with right now.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to set up a testing environment first if you don't have one yet. Install the same ClickHouse version you currently have in production, run realistic workload there, see if everything continues to run fine when you upgrade ClickHouse, fix/adjust if not.

You should also check all "Backward Incompatible Change" sections of https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/changelog/ for all versions you are upgrading over.

Normally people use the latest version marked "stable" that works fine in their testing/preproduction environments.

Comment: Thank you for you're advice i have already set up an environment with Clickhouse 1.1.54343 and i have used Ontime data set and i am running my tests. My ask was in more of pre known challanges if anyone have ever faced them with ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @PrakharNigam official ClickHouse executables are compiled statically which allows to have minimal dependency on which exactly Linux distribution you are running it on. You are talking about upgrade over few years of active development and possible issues depend heavily on specific workload, so I doubt anyone has some definite guide about this.